# Не работает onclick на блоке div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function create() {
  var num = 15;
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "ava";
    div.onclick = function(i) {
      return function() {
        alert(i);
      }
    }(i);
    div.innerHTML = '<strong>' + i + '</strong>';
    div.setAttribute("id", i);
    calb.insertBefore(div, calb.childen);
    test(i);
  }
}
```

```css
.ava {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 65px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #d6e9c6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #3c765f;
  background-color: #C7F7B7;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.ava:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function test(num) {
      $('#' + num).animate({
        opacity: '1'
      }, 5000);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="calb"></div>
  <script>
    create();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Имеется следующие коды:

CSS:

```
.ava {
  opacity:0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 65px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #d6e9c6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #3c765f;
  background-color: #C7F7B7;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.ava:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  text-align: center;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function create() {
var num = 15;
  for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "ava";
    div.onclick = function(i) { return function() { alert(i); }}(i);
    div.innerHTML = '<strong>' + i + '</strong>';
    div.setAttribute("id", i);
    calb.insertBefore(div, calb.childen);
    test(i);
  }
}
```

JQuery:

```
function test (num) 
{
   $('#'+num).animate({opacity:'1'},5000);
}
```

В итоге мы имеем:
 - курсор не пойнтер,
 - онклик не онкликается,
 - анимации при наведении нету.

Проблема появилась после пришивания JQuery. help...

ps: Как вообще должен выглядеть, точнее быть написан, подобный код, выполняющий функции которые этот должен бы выполнять? Спасибо!

Comment: Обратите внимание на кнопочку с подсказкой "Фрагмент кода на ..." в тулбаре режима редактирования вопроса. Используя этот инструмент, Вы можете создать рабочий пример кода, демострирующий Вашу проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С использованием jQuery 2.1.1 и без нарушения спецификации HTML в части формирования `id` DOM-элементов (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html).

```js
function create() {
  var num = 15;
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "ava";
    div.onclick = function(i) {
          return function() {
            alert(i);
          }
    }(i);
    div.innerHTML = '<strong>' + i + '</strong>';
    div.setAttribute("id", "div" + i);
    calb.insertBefore(div, calb.childen);
    test(i);
  }
}

function test(num) {
  //console.log($('#div' + num).length);
  $('#div' + num).animate({
    opacity: '1'
  }, 5000);
}

create();
```

```css
    .ava {
      opacity: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
      float: left;
      width: 65px;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 15px;
      border: 1px solid #d6e9c6;
      border-radius: 4px;
      color: #3c765f;
      background-color: #C7F7B7;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    .ava:hover {
      transform: scale(1.1);
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calb"></div>
```

Comment: так, а тут работает.... В чем причина?

Comment: Написал сверху.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Код испольняется в среднем 10 мс.
Код "Igor" тестил - исполняется в среднем 18-20 мс

Для отпимизации времени я убрал работу с DOM и того цыкл for работает быстрее. 
Используеться 1 команда

```
place.find('.ava').animate({ opacity: '1'}, 5000);
```

Вместо того чтоб вызывать из цыкла функцию. Результат тотже + меньше вызовов, меньшая скорость исполнения.
Смотрите:

```
console.log()
```

Пример: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bearwolf/zyo45o8c/1/)

```js
var a = $.now(),
 place = $('[data-type="square"]');

create();

place.on('click',function(){
  alert($(this).index); 
});

place.find('.ava').animate({
  opacity: '1'
  }, 5000);

b = $.now();
console.log('time:'+(b-a));

function create() {
  var num = 15,
     result = '';
   
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
 result += '<div class="ava" id="div'+i+'"><strong>'+i+'</strong></div>'    
  }
  place.append(result);
}
```

```css
   .ava {
      opacity: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
      float: left;
      width: 65px;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 15px;
      border: 1px solid #d6e9c6;
      border-radius: 4px;
      color: #3c765f;
      background-color: #C7F7B7;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    .ava:hover {
      transform: scale(1.1);
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calb" data-type='square'></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Очень интересный вариант, есть чему поучиться)
У меня появились новые вопросы, как во время создания элементов при помощи ajax узнать в базе данных какого цветы элемент? Или можно использовать post запрос через php? Не подскажете что можно почитать конкретно на эту тему, а то все что я нашел как то размыто и не для новичка)

Comment: Декомпозируйте сложные задачи на более мелкие. Код етих задач должен быть какможно универсальнее... Сначала сформируйте на backend результат на Ваш запрос по цвету.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в синтаксисе если не ошибаюсь:

По правилам нужно `ID` назначать в `""` ковычках как тут `$("#num")`
а у вас как я вижу когда принимается параметр `num` получается вот так:
`$(#num)` что уже не правильно...

попробуйте сделать так:

```
$("\"#"+num+"\"").animate({opacity:'1'},5000);
```

Comment: Проблема отнюдь не с этим, тут все работает)
а вот засунуть все это во "Фрагмент кода на..." проблематично, но сейчас постараюсь)